# What is the correct way to make a systemd service file for monero-wallet-rpc

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I want to setup monero-wallet-rpc as a systemd service. I have attempted to do this with my minimal systemd experience, however I am having some issues.

When I start the service I am not returned to a prompt.

When I stop the service, it continues to run.

It also does not deleted the wallet lock file.

I would also like it to wait for about 60 seconds after the Monero Node starts up. (monero-node.service)

In case it matters I am running this on Ubuntu LTS 16.04

```
[Unit]
Description=Monero Wallet RPC Daemon
After=network.target monero-node.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/monero/bin/monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file=/opt/monero/wallets/monero_wallet.bin --password itsaseceret --daemon-address 172.16.254.80:18081 --rpc-bind-port 8082 --log-file /var/log/monero/monero-rpc.log --rpc-bind-ip 172.16.254.80 --confirm-external-bind --disable-rpc-login

GuessMainPID=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working a little better, however every once n a while, the wallet rpc service stops and tries restart, but can't because the wallet lock file still exits.

```
[Unit]
Description=Monero Wallet RPC Daemon
After=network.target monero-node.service

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
Restart=always
RestartSec=60
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/monero/bin/monero-wallet-rpc --wallet-file=/wallet.bin --password Seceret_Password --daemon-address 172.16.254.80:18081 --rpc-bind-port 8082 --log-file /var/log/monero/monero-rpc.log --rpc-bind-ip 172.16.254.80 --confirm-external-bind --disable-rpc-login

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```